# What is the best way to perform Aggregation / Denormalisation in a database?

Tags: database, aggregation, denormalization

We have a database that stores clicks, views and goals reached. As you can guess the clicks in the database are hitting millions so we started aggregating the data for faster statistics. At this moment we delete all records and write new ones in a aggregation table (you can guess correctly that your mysql keys are going up rapidly) but this is the most easy way to aggregate our statistics without any errors.

I've searched the internet on database aggregation. Like how to store/denormalize your data so you can select the correct data quickly without having to reverence multiple tables. But I found no answer on this.

I'm also guessing that mysql is not the right database to store aggregated data in because the aggregated data will grow fast and could be selected from the begin to the end (like selecting the statistics for a whole year). Is my conclusion right? If so what database would you recommend me?

I also though of splitting the data over multiple tables for multiple solutions but I'm unsure if this would be smart.

My questions are:

- what aggregation techniques are you using to keep your aggregation table correct?
- What database would be the best for storing aggregation in?
- Should I split aggregation over multiple tables? Or should I make one general table that can handle multiple types of data requests?
- How do you handle speed issues?
- Is there a different name for data aggregation?

I'm sorry for the lengthy question :). I've searched SO and the internet and have not found any good answer on these questions.

Comment: You come in quite hard with your "don't tell me this, I did this", but it does help if you post what you actually did, what the results of your quest for information are, and why they don't fit. As is, your question will probably give you some of those answers you discarded in the best case, in the worst case it might be closed as 'too broad', or even 'not constructive' as it might be a discussion-topic // list-topic.

Comment: I've edited it with more info an dropped the attitude :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> What database would be the best for storing aggregation in?

If I understand your definition of "aggreation" I would say that you are removing all relational stuff, so you are probably aiming for some noSQL sollution.

> Should I split aggregation over multiple tables? Or should I make one general table that can >handle multiple types of data requests?

Impossible to say, depends on what you want. What you are doing is de-normalizing so you can get your data quicker. But if you denormalize too much, you can't find the right data. So it really is different for each situation.

> How do you handle speed issues?

Again, impossible to say. Roughly: find out what causes them, and fix the problem.

> Is there a different name for data aggregation?

It look like you are building something of a "Data Warehouse"? See random internets ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse for instance) for more on that.

Comment: Nanne, rather telling on every question hard to say could you please tell me what information you are missing?

Comment: Well, the point I didn't do that was because I doubt it could be answered without having a start. The reason you do this is because of speed issues, so the first step would be to ... wel "do this". Then, you can go from there: is your I/O quick enough, are your indices working for you, can you cut down on some size etc. For the splitting: depends on what information you need to keep. I guess you could start with your current database schema and the final goal for aggregation. But it also depends on speed again. Sorry I can't be more clear then that :)